# Excel vba loops

Tags: excel, vba

How do I fill in columns A and B in Excel (VBA), considering that B should be < 100 000, A contains integers starting from 1 and B contains values n^5-10n^4?

I tried to use a Do While loop but couldn't figure out how to solve this task

Here is the code I tried but I'm sure it is very wrong(I just started with VBA):

```
columnB = Cells(k, 2).Value
columnA = Cells(i, 1).Value
Do Until columnB < 100000
    columnA = columnA + 1
    columnB = columnA ^ 5 - 10 * columnA ^ 4
Loop
```

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? If you're limited to the result being <100,000, then n=13 is your highest possible integer

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the code you tried.  It is hard to help debug if we do not see the code you tried.

Comment: Yes, I do need VBA for this unfortunately

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76104093/edit) to _show_ us what you have tried

Comment: You have your logic backwards: `Do Until columnB >= 100000`

Answer (score 2):

If it absolutely must be VBA, then something like this should work for you. Note that in your original code, you were never setting cell values to your results, you only kept updating the variables. This is some simple code as an example for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
Sub FillValues()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long:          i = 1
    Dim lMax As Long:       lMax = 100000
    
    Dim dValue As Double
    Do
        dValue = i ^ 5 - 10 * i ^ 4
        If dValue >= lMax Then Exit Do
        
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = i
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = dValue
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation! This looks easier than I thought